# Extract website html data between span element using php

Tags: php, curl

I use this code to Extract website html data
and I have a problem with get data between span element
like `<span id="SpanPhoneNumber" dir="ltr">02-26981106</span>` AND `<span id="SpanCurrentBalance">19.30</span>`

```
include_once("simple_html_dom.php");
function getHTML($url,$timeout)
{
       $ch = curl_init($url); // initialize curl with given url
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]); // set  useragent
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // write the response to a variable
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // follow redirects if any
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout); // max. seconds to execute
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1); // stop when it encounters an error
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
       return @curl_exec($ch);
}
$response = getHTML("https://billing.te.eg/Arabic/BillStatus.aspx?Acc=A4000917512",10);
$html = str_get_html($response);

// my problem here - i want get data between span element without loop or array
echo $html->find('span[id=SpanCategory]');
```

Comment: Two questions. First, are you getting the HTML document that you expect? Secondly I notice you have an at-sign @ in front of the curl_exec.  Are you otherwise getting curl-related or resource-related errors?

Comment: @AdamT yes i get the html , like this can i get all images `foreach($html->find("img") as $element)
echo $element->src . '<br>';` , yeah there is error `$html->find` it array i cannot print it by `echo` Secondly when i use `print_r` show me result empety like `array()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`preg_match_all` Could possibly help. I put together a simple one, which may/may not help you since you are using what appears to be a DOM reader/parser.

```
$html_original='<span id="SpanPhoneNumber" dir="ltr">02-26981106</span>';
$html_original .="<p>Some other info here in a paragraph tag</p>";
$html_original .='<span id="SpanCurrentBalance">19.30</span>';

$pattern = '/[0-9-\.]+/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $html_original, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Results in.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 02-26981106
            [1] => 19.30
        )

)
```

Again, it is a primitive regex that is only capturing numbers, I didn't inlclude references to the two Span Elements mentioned in your code.

Lastly, your $`html->find` call references an ID that I didn't see in the opening of your post (you mentioned SpanPhoneNumber and SpanCurrentBalance) - maybe that's the id to use in the ->find command?

Comment: thanx brother , your code of course will be help but i don't want to use `ReGeX` ,I would prefer to edit my code and use `DOM reader/parser` , like `foreach($html->find("img") as $element)
echo $element->src . '<br>';` to get all images OR  `foreach($html->find("a") as $element)
echo $element->href . '<br>';` to get all links , Note : `SpanPhoneNumber and SpanCurrentBalance` that's ids they unique (Non-repeating) in the html code So when i print the result it should not be `array` i want it just `Variable`

Comment: Hi @omardealo thanks for accepting answer. Were you able to get the code to meet your requirement?

Comment: Thank you for following up, I found another code will meet well my order but I am having a another problem on it  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583779/posting-json-data-with-php-curl-and-extract-html-content